# When to Flag a Late Answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer

I recently had a moderator decline a flag I raised on a late-answer review task that seemed like a **clear-cut** example of a "non-answer flag".  I made this decision based on the criteria found here: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

The late answer I'm discussing is here: [Is there any way to bypass NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI when cross site access is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877727/is-there-any-way-to-bypass-ns-error-dom-bad-uri-when-cross-site-access-is-disabl/24938000#24938000)

My question is: what is the appropriate action here if not a flag?

The user in question seems to have been providing several low-quality answers to questions recently and the answer given to this question doesn't even address a point made in the question.  In fact it has more to do with refuting another answer and quoting some unknown user as a source.

In the future, what should I do differently in cases like this?

Comment: That does look like an attempt at answering though. It is a **low quality** answer, so you downvote it, but it *still an attempt at answering*. It is not a 'I have this question too' post. It is not a 'Thanks' post, etc.

Comment: I see your point, but the original question itself doesn't even use the word iframe, this answer seems simply like a "I don't have an answer, but here is x in a list of hundreds of things to not use", no?

Comment: It is still an attempt at answering, in my view. Downvote, move on. If this user persists at such low quality dross, they'll get answer banned anyway.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: No linkie, and *five* paragraphs copied?  Hasn't Buzzfeed Ben taught us *nothing???*  Deleted now.  Should be flagged as Other, with "copied with no attribution from here <link>."